# \n at end of embedded string causes regex to fail to match

Tags: java, regex

Using the below regex's I'm attempting to extract a string value that is contained in double quotes and convert the matches values into a Map. This works as expected for the string `"e,r,t,\"$0 = 1\n$1 = 2\n$5 = 6\",a,b,c,d";` but when I add a `\n` to at end of embedded string : `"e,r,t,\"$0 = 1\n$1 = 2\n$5 = 6\n\",a,b,c,d";` the map is not populated.

src :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadLine {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        final String st = "e,r,t,\"$0 = 1\n$1 = 2\n$5 = 6\n\",a,b,c,d";

        final Pattern quotesPattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"", Pattern.DOTALL);
        final Matcher quotesMatcher = quotesPattern.matcher(st);
        quotesMatcher.find();
        String mv = quotesMatcher.group(0).replace("\n", ", ");
        System.out.println("mv : " + mv);

        final Map<String, String> mappedValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

        final Pattern find = Pattern.compile("(\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *(?:, *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *)*\")");
        final Pattern extract = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\p{Alnum}+) *= *(\\p{Alnum}+)");

        final Matcher matcher = find.matcher(mv);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            final Matcher extractor2 = extract.matcher(matcher.group(0));
            while (extractor2.find())
                System.out.println(extractor2.group(1) +"->"+extractor2.group(2));
        }
    }

}
```

which prints:

```
mv : "$0 = 1, $1 = 2, $5 = 6, "
```

The regex is not matched.

If I use instead :

```
final String st = "e,r,t,\"$0 = 1\n$1 = 2\n$5 = 6\",a,b,c,d";
```

prints :

```
mv : "$0 = 1, $1 = 2, $5 = 6"
0->1
1->2
5->6
```

So the omission of \n allows the regex to match.

I expect

```
0->1
1->2
5->6
```

to matched regardless of if `\n` occurs at end of embedded string or not.

I don't like the fact of using `String mv = quotesMatcher.group(0).replace("\n", ", ");` and there is likely a cleaner way of parsing these values but how to edit so that if `\n` occurs at end of embedded string the values are matched ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `find` regex `Pattern` from

```
(\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *(?:, *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *)*\")
```

to

```
\" *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *(?:, *\\$\\p{Alnum}+ *= *\\p{Alnum}+ *)*(, )?\"
```

The brackets `()` around the regex are not required and, hence, removed.

`(, )?` at the tail end instructs the `matcher` to match even if the *mapped values* string ends with a `,`  and the `?` after it tells the `matcher` that its presence is optional.